# Getting only new data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've run my application which is getting data from SQL Server periodically. The problem here is that I want to get the records created since the last read.

Let me show an example.

At first, (at 12:00:00)

```
Table
---------
orderId orderName
1       name1
2       name2
3       name3
4       name3
```

I'm going to select all data here.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
```

After one minute, some data was added into TABLE like below,

```
Table
---------
orderId orderName
1       name1
2       name2
3       name3
4       name3
5       name4
6       name5
```

At this point, when I select the data like below,

```
select *
from TABLE
```

what I want to get is row no. 5 and row no.6, which is added after I selected before.

My idea is I need to keep an identifier which indicates the transaction of id or something like that but I still don't catch any idea... Can you help me? Any keyword or links helping me?

It would be helpful for me to implement the refresh event to get only new data with the idea I'm expecting.

---

Thank you guys, here's the more specific table I have.

```
Table
---------
orderId      orderTime
1       2017-9-4 8:00:00.000
1       2017-9-4 8:00:10.000
1       2017-9-4 8:00:20.000
1       2017-9-4 8:00:30.000
1       2017-9-4 8:00:40.000
1       2017-9-4 8:00:50.000

2       2017-9-4 8:00:11.000
2       2017-9-4 8:00:20.000
2       2017-9-4 8:00:32.000
2       2017-9-4 8:00:40.000
```

And the time records will be added continuously based on the orderId, respectively. Most idea that I keep the last orderId may not work for my case. How do I handle it in the specific this case?

Comment: *"My idea is I need to keep an identifier which indicates the transaction of id or something like that"* - That's a good direction to start with. Where are you stuck? And what language is the application written in?

Comment: Why not keep the last value of `orderId` in a variable and run `select * from table where orderId > yourvariable`?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `change data capture` or `change tracking`? Whether either of those are the right approach depends on a number of other factors - such as what you need w.r.t. updates and deletes.

Comment: 'change data capture' is the built in way to do this. Or you can build your own, if you have a method to identify new data. In your example, it's obvious that you can just store the last orderId loaded, but your real data may not be like that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I've already searched for it and it doesn't work for my version, sql-server is workgroup edition. That's only for the enterprise or developer version... :

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, I'm gonna try to do that keeping the last id.

Comment: @KobyDouek Java. Tbh, I didn't come up with any idea where to start but I think I can start by those comments above including you!

Comment: @MatSnow That's a good idea. Let me try it!

Comment: "Most idea that I keep the last orderId may not work for my case. How do I handle it in the specific this case?" We do not have the slightest clue as you have not explained the case for which it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

There not any keyword to identify latest entry of last execution. Because, your query run both the time on different session. So, you can't identify it.

But Basically, we have other option to do this task.

1. Do it with Maintaining Max value of identifier. Maintain it into the variable, Session, Parameter, etc...

   ```
   select * 
   from table 
   where orderId > yourvariableValue
   ```

Comment: I've updated the real table then in this case, it seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: you have to replace the identifier through DateTime and need to store the time And Compare it with time field only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always save somewhere the largest `orderId` you've got at your last `select` and then, knowing that `orderId`, use it in your `select`, like this:

```
select ...
from ...
where orderId > 4
```

Comment: It's a good idea but in my case, it's more complicated. Sorry I didn't let you know earlier. it might be quite different...

Answer (score 0):

Store the last orderId **and** the associated last orderTime in a variable.

This should work as you want.

```
DECLARE @lastOrderId int = 2
DECLARE @lastOrderTime datetime = '2017-9-4 8:00:40.000'

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (orderId = @lastOrderId AND orderTime > @lastOrderTime) OR orderId > @lastOrderId
ORDER BY orderId, orderTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of vague suggestions for saving in sessions, variables etc. I suggest you just use the table itself:

Find the last key in the local table:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(OrderID),0) FROM TABLE
```

Use that to decide what to select out from your remote table

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT
SELECT @MaxID = ISNULL(MAX(OrderID),0) FROM TABLE


INSERT INTO TABLE (OrderID, Col1, Col2)
SELECT OrderID, Col1, Col2
FROM REMOTETABLE
WHERE OrderID > @MaxID
```

I see you have a recent edit saying this may not work. You need to explain why otherwise no one has any chance of helping. Is it because the OrderID might not always increment? Can it go backwards? You need to explain.